Analyzing Divergence and Convergence in Integrals
I am trying to find the integral of
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x^2 - 3}{(x^2 - 2x + 3)(x^2 + 2x + 3)} \, dx$$
First,
$\displaystyle{
\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x^2 - 3}{(x^2 - 2x + 3)(x^2 + 2x + 3)} \, dx
= \frac{1}{2} \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x - 1}{x^2 - 2x + 3} \, dx
- \frac{1}{2} \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x + 1}{x^2 + 2x + 3} \, dx
}$
Let $u=x^2-2x+3 $, $du = (2x-2) \, dx$, and $v=x^2+2x+3$,  $dv = (2x+2)  dx$
$\displaystyle{
= \frac{1}{4} \int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u} \, du
- \frac{1}{4} \int_{6}^{\infty} \frac{1}{v} \, dv
= \frac{1}{4} \left[  \int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u} \, du - \int_{6}^{\infty} \frac{1}{v} \, dv \right]
}$
I have two possible interpretations in the following step:

Divergence Interpretation:
Both integrals involving to infinity, which suggests that the original problem might be unsolvable .

Convergence Interpretation:
We can combine two integral into:
$$
= \frac{1}{4} \left[  \int_{2}^{6} \frac{1}{y} \, dy \right] =\frac{1}{4} \left.[  \ln y \right]_{2}^{6}= \frac{1}{4} \ln 3 $$


Which interpretation is valid, and why?

Duplicate?

Since the integrand function does not have poles over the interval of integration, you just have to study the behaviour at infinity. Note that $f(x)\sim 1/x^2$ as $x\to +\infty$

Your statement immediately following "First..." is not correct, both definite integrals on the RHS diverge.

finish the integration up to some large positive real number $M.$ At this stage, everything is defined, one may combine the separated integrals, finally take limit as $M \longrightarrow \infty $  You have most of it, what is $\frac{1}{4} \left[  \int_{2}^{M} \frac{1}{u} , du - \int_{6}^{M} \frac{1}{v} , dv \right] $

Second interpretation is valid as we are looking for the convergence of the difference and not convergence of individual integrals

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int_1^{\infty} \frac{x^2-3}{\left(x^2-2 x+3\right)\left(x^2+2 x+3\right)} d x \\
= & \frac{1}{2}\left[\int_1^{\infty} \frac{x-1}{x^2-2 x+3} d x-\int_1^{\infty} \frac{x+1}{x^2+2 x+3} d x\right] \\
= & \frac{1}{2}\left[\int_1^{\infty} \frac{x-1}{(x-1)^2+1} d x-\int_1^{\infty} \frac{x+1}{(x+1)^2+1} d x\right. \\
= & \frac{1}{4}\left[\ln \left[(x-1)^2+1\right]-\ln \left[(x+1)^2+1\right]_1^{\infty}\right. \\
= & \frac{1}{4}\left[\ln \left(\frac{x^2-2 x+3}{x^2+2 x+3}\right)\right]_1^{\infty} \\
= & \frac{1}{4} \ln 3
\end{aligned}
$$
